# AWS IoT certificate file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm struggling with the client cert and private key embedding or uploading, in order to authenticate with the AWS IoT endpoint assigned to my account. We are currently working in a solution in order to embed that ideal solution of the two certs and the private key at the gateway hardware which will forward the information sent by the sensor in a secure way.

I would like to know if there are any way to connect in the same way of Google IoT (JWT in the password field) o Azure (SAS token in password field) and not have to use the files: private key, CA certificate, certificate x509

The deviced I'm using are MQTT, so I can not use HTTP or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different possibilities using different protocols, see the Message Broker Protocols topic in the AWS IoT Developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

Using the MQTT protocol directly, you have to use certificates, but if you use the MQTT + WebSocket option, you can either use a standard AWS Signature V4 header on the connect request, or you can use a custom authorizer (and your own header on the connect request).

Good starters for understanding those options are
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-custom-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, Dave. Can I do with V4 someting like the "SAS token" in Azure IoT Hub. I mean, If  I want to connect to AWS IoT can I use only the username, CA certificate and in the password field put the AWS signature v4 (like the SAS token I said)